# how to host angular and node js project on the shared hosting (cpanel or plesk)?

Tags: node.js, cpanel, plesk

I have two different shared hosting on GoDaddy server (cPanel and Plesk odin), I want to host my NodeJS project there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You CAN do this.**

Most tutorials have you downloading node + npm through the command line... and since you cannot use *sudo* in terminal on a shared GoDaddy server you have to install nvm to install npm and node.

But really, you only need a *single file* from the Node.js package to get a server running. It is much easier to download the package, and manually add the one file to cPanel.

Follow [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54121109/10499018) for the most simple method of running a Node.js server on GoDaddy hosting.

---

<strike>You can't host Node project on cpanel. You will need a node server for that. Cpanel does not come with node installed, neither it could be Installed. You can check with aws or blueocean for that.</strike>