# Node Segmentation Fault for any node command with very basic code

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why am I getting a `segmentation fault` error whenever I type in any node commands?

A bit of background information: I'm trying to deploy any basic demo node app (in GoDaddy's shared hosting) following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146067/i-have-godaddy-shared-web-hosting-i-need-to-host-node-js-website-can-host-site/42234844#42234844) instructions (from the comment from user called 'x.g.'). I do everything and get to the very last instruction (number 5) where it states to type `node app.js &` and I get the following response in the terminal:

```
[1] 326516
```

If I type `node app.js` without the ampersand & I get this error:

```
Segmentation fault
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it? I basically have (as per the instructions) an app.js with this simple code:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('NodeJS server running on Shared Hosting\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log('Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/');
});
```

Also, whenever I type anything like `node`, `npm` or `node-v` it also states the `Segmentation fault` error. Any help would be much appreciated!

**Update:** any ideas anyone?

Comment: It's unlikely this has anything to do with your Javascript.  This is likely an installation issue with nodejs.

Comment: could be. Do you know what specific part of the installation with node it could be?

Comment: How did you install node? It looks like you installed a version of node.js that is incompatible with your OS/distro