# Deploying a Sapper app on GoDaddy shared hosting with cPanel

Tags: javascript, cpanel, web-deployment, shared-hosting, sapper

I am new to web development and have never deployed an app before.
I have bought a domain, ssl, and shared hosting through go daddy and am trying to deploy a simple Sapper app.

I have been able to deploy a basic node.js app by following this thread [I have Godaddy Shared Web Hosting I need to host node.js website can host site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146067/i-have-godaddy-shared-web-hosting-i-need-to-host-node-js-website-can-host-site/42234844#42234844)

I have uploaded my app folder into the user/public_html folder and can successfully build the app by running:

**node **sapper**/build**

The terminal replies with *"Starting server on port 3000"* which doesn't change anything.
My guess is I need to modify my server.js but I am really out of my depth (it's using polka btw).
If someone could please help me deploy the app correctly and how to integrate the ssl certificates it would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you currently running the node server described in the linked post?  I am assuming you went with the second option (Standalone Server)?

Comment: Yep I followed along with the standalone server answer. After that I deleted the app.js file and now have my app folder in there it seems to be building fine but I'm not sure how to get it to show up on my domain.

Comment: When you say it doesn't change anything, what exactly do you mean? When you try to visit the page is it displaying the "NodeJS server running on..." message or something else?

Comment: When I followed that persons instructions, my domain url page changed and just displayed the response from the node server like it's meant to. Although now I've deleted all that, my domain just displays the default template that cPanel provides even though I seem to have my sapper app running on the server. So yeah I'm lost trying to figure out how to get my sapper app to show up on my domain

Comment: Did you keep the  .htaccess file?