# permission error when trying to run node server in godaddy

Tags: node.js, cpanel

im trying to run a nodejs server on godaddy using the cpanel thing. i followed [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146067/i-have-godaddy-shared-web-hosting-i-need-to-host-node-js-website-can-host-site/42234844#42234844), and got to the part where you run the server file. however, the server gives me a permission error.

[image]

there may be something wrong with my file structure, or the tutorial may be out of date, as my file structure differed from that in the tutorial. ex: tutorial said to go to /home/username/public_html, but my public_html folder is located on the root folder.

Update:
i just found that i could change file permissions, and enable the execute option on the node file. i'm now getting a segmentation fault error

[image]

if you need any extra information, let me know.

Comment: chmod +x filename . similarly check node by running this command node -v. To ensure your node binary is able to execute

Comment: not sure if im doing what you asked properly or not, but i ran chmod +x app.js and got no output, and ran node -v and got permission denied

Comment: ill try a different version of node for now

Comment: That is not related the node version, for the node you need to give execute permission. Ex. chmod +x /home/tpa378rcliql/bin/node

Comment: try using `sudo node app.js` maybe  node is installed for root users only

Comment: run this command and send the output `cd /home/tpa378rcliql/bin && ls -la | grep node` this command shows you the permissions given to node executable

Comment: sorry for the long reply, here's the output:
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tpa378rcliql tpa378rcliql 74274016 Oct 26 02:38 node*

Comment: also SaGaR it looks like sudo isnt even installed (or im an idiot, i dont know linux well at all).
tpa378rcliql@p3plzcpnl487228 [~/bin]$ sudo -v
bash: sudo: command not found