# GoDaddy Hosted Server Not Respoding to Requests

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, hosting

I'm using GoDaddy shared hosting, and I was able to follow these very helpful [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146067/i-have-godaddy-shared-web-hosting-i-need-to-host-node-js-website-can-host-site) to SSH into the server. I'm also able to start the server successfully. I have `server.js`, `script.js`, `index.html` and `styles.css` all in the same directory (the default one, which is `public_html`). The problem is that making a GET request to `/getRequest` or even the root /, doesn't work, even if it does locally when accessing `localhost:3000`. I couldn't get all of these working together when accessing my site at `example.com`, so I tried to create a more simple server. I still can't get this to work. Same problem happens where it works locally but not online. When trying online, the request to both the root and `example.com/getRequest` aren't found. The `/getRequest` shows a 404 when inspecting in browser, and the request to the root returns the default 'Coming Soon' page. Why is the server unable to respond to requests? Is this some misconfiguration I've done through GoDaddy?

Edit: In continuing to search, I thought this [article](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/add-a-subdomain-4080) would help. Unfortunately the article uses subdomain like **data**.example.com instead of example.com/data. Still don't know how to configure the server to respond to these requests.

server.js is:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

//app.get('/getRequest', (req, res) => {
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const variableString = "Hello, world!";
  
   
  res.json({ variableString });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://${hostname}:${port}`);
});
```

and script.js is (with 'host' and 'port' variables coming from the output from the server when it first starts):

```js
//fetch('{myHost}:{myPort}/getRequest')
fetch('{myHost}:{myPort}')
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.message);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
    });
```

Comment: Are you including the port number in your Godaddy URL?  What port number are you starting the server at?  What is the URL you are trying to then check?

Comment: I'm just accessing my website using the domain name. Port number is 3000. I'm not using example.com:3000, I just try to access example.com

Comment: You need the port number in the URL or you need to set up godsddys main server to reverse proxy the requests

Comment: I tried adding the port number but sadly, that still didn't work. Why would that be?? Maybe I can try the reverse proxy. How do I do that?

Comment: See step 9 https://stackoverflow.com/a/53449335/1145388

Comment: Thanks so much!! The port number didn't work but the reverse proxy did!